# Find dynamic video src and append the src as a link

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm trying to grab the src of a dynamic HTML5 video, and append the src as a link below the video so it can be downloaded. I don't have direct access to the markup so I can't adjust the video player's settings to accommodate this, so I've been trying to do it with jQuery but can't get my head around what the correct syntax would be.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="player">
    <video><source src="video.mp4"></video>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
  var video = $('.wrapper video')[0];
  $("#player").prepend($(video).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `source` tag, in your jquery.

```
$(function() {
  var video = $('.wrapper video')[0];
  $("#player").prepend('<a href=' + $("source", video).attr('src') + ' >link</a>');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  var video = $('.wrapper video')[0];
  $("#player").prepend('<a href=' + $("source", video).attr('src') + ' >link</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="player">
    <video><source src="video.mp4"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```